# Can you apply a modifier that adds new vertices (like subdivision surface) without changing vertex group boundaries?

Tags: scripting, subdivision-surface, vertex-groups

When I apply an SS modifier to an object with this vertex group:
[image]

I get this vertex group:

[image]

But I'm really hoping to get this vertex group:
[image]

I understand the reason why blender does it this way, and the issues that arise from trying to do it my way, but I'm writing an addon that requires the vertex group boundaries to stay the same after applying modifiers like SS and Bevel. Is this possible? Since this is for an addon, ways to do it through script would be preferable. Thanks

Comment: If it's solidly weighted, you can follow it up with a vertex weight edit modifier with a custom curve to drop the 0.5 weights to zero, and, if you want, a vertex edit mix modifier to remove 0 weight verts from the group.  But is it solidly weighted?  If it's not, that will also affect the other weights.

Comment: Ah yeah the groups I care about are solidly weighted so that could work. Thanks my guy

Comment: I guess you don't actually need the edit modifier, just the mix modifier-- then you can just remove anything with a threshold of 0.5 or lower.